# how to get least possible count on graphite graph

Tags: ruby, graphite, statsd

```
require 'statsd'

statsd = Statsd.new('localhost', 8125).tap{|sd| sd.namespace = 'account'}

1.times do
  statsd.increment 'hitcount4'
end

sleep 5

5.times do
  statsd.increment 'hitcount4'
end

sleep 10

10.times do
  statsd.increment 'hitcount4'
end
```

i am using ruby gem `statsd-ruby`

i ran the above script it executes successfully, and the graph appears but i can just see the a line over the x-axis and nothing (no value for y-axis), how to get the graph for above script?

i want to record each increment call.

contents of /opt/graphite/statsd/local.js

```
{
  graphitePort: 2003
, graphiteHost: "127.0.0.1"
, port: 8125
, backends: [ "./backends/graphite", "./backends/repeater", "./backends/console" ]
, repeater: [ { host: '10.1.2.15', port: 8125 } ]
, graphite: { legacyNamespace: false, globalPrefix: "rtpg.testing_server_2" }
, flushInterval: 10
}
```

contents of /opt/graphite/conf/storage-schemas.conf

```
[carbon]
pattern = ^carbon\.
retentions = 60:90d

[stats]
pattern = ^stats.*
retentions = 1s:6h,10min:10d,10min:5y

[rtpg]
pattern = ^rtpg.*
retentions = 1s:7d,10s:21d,60s:5y
```

contents of /opt/graphite/conf/storage-aggregation.conf

```
[rtpg]
pattern = .*
xFilesFactor = 0
aggregationMethod = sum


[sum]
pattern = \.count$
xFilesFactor = 0
aggregationMethod = sum
```

with,

> localhost:8090/render?target=rtpg.testing_server_2.counters.account.hitcount4.count&format=raw
>
> output on browser =>
>
> ..........0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0

with

> //localhost:8090/render?target=rtpg.testing_server_2.counters.account.hitcount4.count&format=json
>
> output =>
>
> ....................[0.0, 1381608024], [0.0, 1381608025], [0.0,
>   1381608026], [0.0, 1381608027], [0.0, 1381608028], [0.0, 1381608029],
>   [0.0, 1381608030], [0.0, 1381608031], [0.0, 1381608032], [0.0,
>   1381608033], [0.0, 1381608034], [0.0, 1381608035], [0.0, 1381608036],
>   [0.0, 1381608037], [0.0, 1381608038], [0.0, 1381608039], [0.0,
>   1381608040], [0.0, 1381608041], [0.0, 1381608042], [0.0, 1381608043],
>   [0.0, 1381608044], [0.0, 1381608045], [0.0, 1381608046], [0.0,
>   1381608047], [0.0, 1381608048], [0.0, 1381608049], [0.0, 1381608050],
>   [0.0, 1381608051], [0.0, 1381608052], [0.0, 1381608053], [0.0,
>   1381608054], [0.0, 1381608055], [0.0, 1381608056]]}]

i updated flush intervel(statsd) to 6000, and updated

/opt/graphite/conf/storage-schemas.conf

```
[carbon]
pattern = ^carbon\.
retentions = 60:90d

[rtpg]
pattern = ^rtpg.*
retentions = 1m:6h,1m:7d,10m:5y
```

and ran whisper-resize.py and updated counter name to 'hitcount6' in my script and ran the script again, a new graph was created, the problem still exists, actually what i want is graphite to show exact count like first increment, then sleep of 5 minutes and then 5 increments and so on, i don't want to average my data, finally i will create a xml report of how many times increment method was invoked. 
$ whisper-info.py /opt/graphite/storage/whisper/rtpg/testing_server_2/counters/account/hitcount6/count.wsp

```
maxRetention: 604800
xFilesFactor: 0.0
aggregationMethod: sum
fileSize: 120988

Archive 0
retention: 604800
secondsPerPoint: 60
points: 10080
size: 120960
offset: 28
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you see (non-null) values in graphite if you "break out" the url and add &format=json or &format=raw to the end of the querystring?

Comment: @MattSelf yes, i am getting `0.0`

Comment: @MattSelf updated question with more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Long story short: **You cannot flush Statsd at an interval lower than 1 second** when using Graphite as the backend.

Because you've specified a flushInterval of 10 ms, StatsD will flush the aggregated data-point every 10 milliseconds of which Graphite will drop 99 out of 100 (all but one of the 10ms flushes).

*First*, setting it this low defeats some of the purpose of Statsd in that it is intended to act as an aggregator that can reduce load on graphite.  *Second*, setting it to anything lower than 1 second will result in lost metric data.  This is because the finest precision that you can store in Graphite is 1 second.  So you'll send 100 data points to graphite per second and Graphite will only store 1 of them.  You'd have to be pretty lucky to see any data (as it will take the last metric (overwriting the others) for the interval.

You must **match the flush interval in StatsD to the finest precision schema setting in Graphite** (in the storage-schema configuration).  The lowest you can go is one second, but 10 seconds is recommended so that StatsD can do some significant aggregation work on your behalf.

I'd recommend you **change the finest (first) precision to 10 seconds**, i.e. `10s:6h` and `10s:7d` for the retentions (and the Statsd flushInterval to 10000 ms) so that Statsd and Graphite line up nicely.

*Next*, make the above change and then **resize the whisper files** to ensure the settings have taken.  Perhaps you changed the graphite schema or aggregation settings after metrics were stored (in whisper = graphite's storage) and you still need to either delete the .wsp files for the metric (graphite will recreate them) or run `whisper-resize.py`.  The whisper files are in `/graphite/storage/whisper/`.

*Finally*, **validate the settings**.  You can verify the settings against some whisper data by running whisper-info.py on a .wsp file. Find the .wsp file for one of your metrics in /graphite/storage/whisper/
Run: `whisper-info.py my_metric_data.wsp`. whisper-info.py output should tell you more about how the storage settings are working.

Comment: still the same issue, but one more thing in /opt/graphite/statsd/local.js, flushInterval: 10, is in millisecond not in seconds.

Comment: It appears the storage-schema retention settings still do not match the statsd flush interval.  I assume you meant the flushInterval to be 60000 ms (1 min) instead of 6000 ms (6 seconds), at which point it would match your storage-schema setting of 1m:6h.  These values have to match. I'd go with the standard statsd flush interval of 10 seconds (10000) with storage-schema finest precision of 10s:6h just to see things working.  Afterward, you can attack the granularity of storage in graphite. Finest possible is 1 second and statsd will manage the aggregation.

Comment: There still could be other issues happening, but first things first, you absolutely need to ensure that secondsPerPoint returned from whisper-info is equal to the flushInterval in StatsD.  Otherwise, you will have data-loss.

Comment: finally got the interesting result, its summing up the count(1+5+10=16), but i don't want this i want it to show 1, 5, 10 independently, should i change aggregationMethod  in storage-aggregation.conf from `sum` to something else, please suggest the correct method.

Comment: and finally i don't want graphite to average my data at any point time.

Comment: No, sum is what you want when trying to track counts, etc.  Did you reduce the flushInterval and storage-schema settings?  You should probably make it either 1 second or 10 seconds... since it seems you'd like a finer grained reporting.  But remember, this will be the sum of all data per every second interval or per every 10 second interval.  Graphite will always store a data-point for each interval (and statsd will flush) regardless of if your application sent data.