# Grafana show only minute scale

Tags: c#, grafana, statsd

I'm a newby in Grafana and start with simple application, which write data each second:

```
    internal class Program
{
    private static Logger Logger { get; } = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        Logger.Info("Starting");
        Do1();

        Logger.Info("Press enter to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    private static void Do1()
    {
        Metrics.Configure(new MetricsConfig
        {                
            StatsdServerName = "metrics.globogames.local",                
            Prefix = "dev.MetricsTest"
        });

        var rand = new Random();
        for (var i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            var val = rand.Next(10000);

            Logger.Info(val);

            Metrics.GaugeAbsoluteValue("gauge-absolute6", val);

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

I use *Statsd C# Client* for send data. So I expect to see in my metric "gauge-absolute6" values for each second. But I see this:
[image]

Diagram contains values only for each minute! If I use export to CSV, I see same picture:

```
sep=;
Series;Time;Value
stats.gauges.dev.MetricsTest.gauge-absolute6;2018-01-31T07:40:00.000Z;5482
stats.gauges.dev.MetricsTest.gauge-absolute6;2018-01-31T07:41:00.000Z;4344
stats.gauges.dev.MetricsTest.gauge-absolute6;2018-01-31T07:42:00.000Z;7286
stats.gauges.dev.MetricsTest.gauge-absolute6;2018-01-31T07:43:00.000Z;2527
stats.gauges.dev.MetricsTest.gauge-absolute6;2018-01-31T07:44:00.000Z;1744
```

Is the problem in my code, Grafana or my metrics?

*How can I see diagram with **values** for **each second**?*

**UPD**:

after i change my carbon/storage-schemas.conf from

```
[default_1min_for_1day]
pattern = .*
retentions = 60s:1d

[statsd]
pattern = ^stats.*
retentions = 10s:1d,1m:7d,10m:1y
```

to

```
[statsd]
pattern = ^stats.*
retentions = 10s:1d,1m:7d,10m:1y

[default_1min_for_1day]
pattern = .*
retentions = 60s:1d
```

it strart shows each 10 seconds. But i still need each 1 second, so i try to do like this

```
[statsd]
pattern = ^stats.*
retentions = 1s:1d,1m:7d,10m:1y
```

and diagramm disappear at all!

**UPD2**:
i also try to add StatsD *flushInterval: 1000* to statsd/localConfig.js:

```
{
  graphitePort: 2003
, graphiteHost: "localhost"
, port: 8125
, graphite: {
    legacyNamespace: false
  }
, flushInterval: 1000
}
```

**Is it possible to set period 1s**?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, there is my solution.

First of all, very good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19318461/how-to-get-least-possible-count-on-graphite-graph)

Shortly: Yes, u can set period 1 second:

[image]

For this u have to change 2 config.

1. storage-schemas.conf

1.1. add rule

```
[statsd]
pattern = ^stats.*
retentions = 1s:1d,1m:7d,10m:1y
```

1.2. this rull MUST be before rule for all:

```
[carbon]
pattern = ^carbon\.
retentions = 60:90d

[statsd]
pattern = ^stats.*
retentions = 1s:1d,1m:7d,10m:1y

[default_1min_for_1day]
pattern = .*
retentions = 60s:1d
```

2.statsd/localConf.js

2.1. Add (or change) flash interval

```
, flushInterval: 1000
```

like this:

```
{
  graphitePort: 2003
, graphiteHost: "localhost"
, port: 8125
, graphite: {
    legacyNamespace: false
  }
, flushInterval: 1000
}
```

3. **flushInterval *MUST* be *EQUAL* retentions *minimum value*** in statsd section